# How to parse Nginx configuratilon files?

Tags: c, parsing, nginx

I would like to find a way to parse `nginx` configuration files in order to dynamically generate diagrams that I would use as documentation.

The `nginx` configuration file syntax looks like this (this example is intentionally basic for conciseness, the configuration files I manage are actually much more complex):

```
location / {
   if (GET) {
      echo_exec @memcache;
   }
   if (POST) {
      echo_exec @application;
   }
}

location @memcache {
   # try to get content from cache
   if (notfound) {
       # fallback to application
       echo_exec @application;
   }
}
location @application {
   # forwarding request to application
}
```

and I would like to generate diagrams such as this one (when moving mouse over a process box you would see the comments, which directives are being called...):

[image]

As far as I know `nginx` configuration file syntax is custom. I was able to find the parser in the source inside `src/core/ngx_conf_file.c` which is something like this:

```
        case ';':
        case '{':
            if (cf->args->nelts == 0) {
                ngx_conf_log_error(NGX_LOG_EMERG, cf, 0,
                                   "unexpected \"%c\"", ch);
                return NGX_ERROR;
            }

            if (ch == '{') {
                return NGX_CONF_BLOCK_START;
            }

            return NGX_OK;
```

Unfortunately I'm clueless about `C` so wouldn't know how to re-use that code.

**Do you know if `nginx` configuration file syntax is close to another known syntax for which parsers already exist that I would be able to re-use and tweak for my needs?**

Comment: This class seems to do what you desire: http://code.google.com/p/hypoconf/source/browse/lib/hypoconf/lib/HypoConf/ConfigParser.php?r=552d5c93d3d01e82f841931c8882c9577838f7ba It's in php though.

Comment: I hope that by mentioning `PHP` people won't loose interest in the question :) `PHP` is my preferred language so that class (i.e. `hypoconf`) would be ideal, it just seems that development efforts have stopped mostly around March 2011 (http://code.google.com/p/hypoconf/source/list).

Answer (score 4):

You may want to look at [Config::Neat](https://github.com/iafan/Config-Neat) Perl module which I just published on GitHub. I came across your question when searching for similar config parser written in Perl, but didn't find any decent one.

Config::Neat is inspired by nginx configuration syntax, though it doesn't require semicolons at the end of each line, and does not [yet] support blocks with the same name. But nevertheless, it might serve you as starting point.

Comment: Looks interesting and should allow easy generation of graphs, for instance by using a `python` wrapper for `Graphiz` (http://www.graphviz.org/Resources.php)

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of hypoconf. The project is not dead, I just renamed it to NAPKIN and moved to github. I'll put a note on the Google Code page now so that people know.
I didn't have time to finish it yet, so last commit is from 9 months ago, so still no 1.0/beta, but the software basically works if you know how to operate it (no documentation so far, and only generates nginx config files). I do intend on completing it though, as soon as I find some spare time.

The problem with your request is that the parser I wrote is for *generating* config files from stored in memory values (which are read earlier from YAML), not the other way around - not analysing them.
The good news is, writing a new parser for what you need, based on my code (or even from scratch) should be relatively easy. It would be much, muuuch simpler than what I have there. But then, I haven't commented the code yet, so it's a true mess finding your way around it.

The quickest way to parse a config file would be to go through it line by line, use something like my [SuperStack class](https://github.com/niieani/napkin/blob/master/lib/hypoconf/lib/Tools/SuperStack.php) to build the whole config as an associative array, and then just print the array or dump it as a picture using some preprogrammed magic.
The only problem I see here are the IF's and how to treat them, but it should be easy enough to work out.

Anyhow, it would be an interesting feature to add to NAPKIN.

I'll send you an email to continue this thought.

Comment: Any word on a release?

Comment: Hard to say, I've moved on to some other projects now, but the code is almost production-ready, though there's no documentation there -  [GitHub](https://github.com/niieani/napkin). I've moved onto writing it as a bash script with support for LXC and other tools, but I'm just starting to write the documentation for that. Supports lots of what napkin did. It's called [SANEi](https://github.com/niieani/sanei).